# jython max function in an array

Tags: arrays, max, jython

```
a=[[10,1],[2,8]]
```

I need to find the max number in 2nd column of the above array.

How to do it in jython.

Simply doing `max(a)[1]` will give 1.

Thanks in advance.

-Suresh

Answer (score 0):

For [jython 2.5](http://www.jython.org/docs/library/functions.html) onwards ...

```
print max(a,key=lambda v:int(v[1]))[1]
```

Otherwise you're probably stuck with a loop ...

```
m = None

for v in a:
  if m is None or v[1] > m:
    m = v[1]

print m
```